# Getting error on SSL impentation on Tomcat 8

Tags: tomcat, ssl

I configured SSL on Tomcat 8 but getting the error on running the link `https://localhost:8443`

```
<Connector 
   port="8443" 
   protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
   maxHttpHeaderSize="1048576" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75" 
   enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true" useBodyEncodingForURI="true" acceptCount="100" 
   scheme="https" 
   secure="true" 
   clientAuth="false" 
   sslProtocol="TLS" 
   keystoreFile="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\old\bbmwtapx01.ad.bgep.co.uk.jks‌​"       
   keystorePass="****" 
   keyAlias="bbmwtapx01.ad.bgep.co.uk"/>
```

This site can’t provide a secure connection
localhost sent an invalid response.
Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Please help me on this. I tried many options but not able to run on https.

Thank-you in Advance
Thanks,
Neha

Comment: <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" maxHttpHeaderSize="1048576"
maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true" useBodyEncodingForURI="true"
acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true"
clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
keystoreFile="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\old\bbmwtapx01.ad.bgep.co.uk.jks" keystorePass="****"
keyAlias="bbmwtapx01.ad.bgep.co.uk"/>

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `SSLEnabled="true"`. The default value is false

See https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html

> Use this attribute to enable SSL traffic on a connector. To turn on SSL handshake/encryption/decryption on a connector set this value to true. **The default value is false.**

Comment: Thanks for reply!!   I have added SSLEnable = "true"   ...Now getting the error as :

14-Dec-2016 21:03:17.205 SEVERE [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio2-8443"]
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.io.IOException: Alias name bbmwtapx01.ad.bgep.co.uk does not identify a key entry

Comment: This message means that there is not any certificate called `bbmwtapx01.ad.bgep.co.uk` in your JKS. Check which certificates are in the keystore with `keytool -list -v -keystore keystore.jks`

Comment: It has 3 entries : 

Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 3 entrie

Alias name: root
Creation date: Dec 9, 2016
Entry type: trustedCertEntry
Extensions:


Alias name: bbmwtapx01.ad.bgep.
Creation date: Dec 9, 2016
Entry type: trustedCertEntry

I think I need to export private key ..Do you have any idea how we can do that ?

Comment: Please, one question at a time. The value you have to set in `keyAlias` is the "alias name" listed from the JKS. It should correspond with a key pair  (private + public key) of a SSL certificate. To import a key pair into JKS, you have a lot of examples in SO. Alternatively you can use the tool KeyStoreExplorer (http://www.keystore-explorer.org/)

Comment: Can you please give me an example to import a key pair into JKS. I am not sure which one i need to perform ..

Comment: Hi @Neha, did you solve the issue? Remenber you can mark the answer as accepted if you think it solves your question